When using Diagnostics.Process, blocks UI in WinForms C# 5.0
I need to create app that runs different commands (PowerShell.exe, ipconfig, etc.), but when the ExecuteCommand is called the UI freezes until work is finished.
Tried to run the method using await proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEndAsync(), but is not working. (it hangs on the mentioned line and is not continuing on the next line)
What I'm doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.
ExecuteCommand:
    public static async Task<string> ExecuteCommand(string command)
    {
        try
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/c " + command);
            procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            procStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

            proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
            proc.Start();

            proc.WaitForExit();
            var message = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEndAsync();

            //var error =  await proc.StandardError.ReadToEndAsync();

            proc.Close();

            //var errorContent = error;
            return message.Result;
        }
        catch (Exception objException)
        {
            return objException.Message;
        }
    }

Logger:
public void Logger(string value)
{
    logtxt.AppendText("[" + DateTime.Now + "]: " + value + Environment.NewLine);
    logtxt.SelectionStart = logtxt.Text.Length;
    logtxt.ScrollToCaret();
}

IsActive:
private async Task<bool> IsActive()
{
    string text = await ExecuteCommand("PowerShell.exe -Command \"Get-VPNconnection -AllUserConnection\"");

    Logger(text);

    ...more code...
}

Form1_Shown (I moved the below code from Form_Load, cause it takes time until the UI appears):
private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsActive().Result)
    {
      ...more code...
    }
}


await [Process].WaitForExitAsync()

also missing await on ReadToEndAsync

This is a common issue with winforms unless you allow the process to run in background mode.  Not sure, but Jimi may have the answer.

Neither PowerShell.exe or ipconfig.exe require any involvement of "cmd", so I'm not understanding why you are using cmd /c first, or more correctly Environment.SystemDirectory with \cmd.exe /S /D /C "command"

Here is your problem:
private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsActive().Result)
    {
      ...more code...
    }
}

Reading the Result property is a blocking operation. Not only it blocks the UI thread, but even worse it causes a deadlock because there are awaits in the asynchronous flow that are capturing the UI context, because they are not configured with .ConfiguredAwait(false). The correct way to solve this problem is to go async-all-the-way:
private async void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (await IsActive())
    {
      ...more code...
    }
}

You can learn more about this common issue, by reading Stephen Cleary's famous article Don't block on async code.

its working like I wanted, thank you
